# Parametric Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, proof, stochastic-integral

I need help.

Defining the parametric stochastic integral

$$
F_t = \int_t^T\xi(t,s)g(s)ds
$$

$\\\\$

with $\xi$ a generic stochastic process such that $d\xi(t,s) = \mu(t,s)dt + \sigma(t,s)dW_t$, I'm trying to prove that

$\\\\$
$$ dF_t = - g(t)\xi(t,t)dt + \int_t^Td\xi(t,s)g(s)ds$$

My first attempt was as follows :

$$
\xi(t,s) = \xi(0,s)  + \int_0^t\mu(u,s)du + \int_0^t \sigma(u,s)dW_u
$$

and so

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_t &=& \int_t^T\xi(0,s)g(s)ds + \int_t^T\int_0^t\mu(u,s)g(s)duds + \int_t^T\int_0^t\sigma(u,s)g(s)dW_uds\\
&=& \int_t^T\xi(s,s)g(s)ds - \int_t^T\int_t^s\mu(u,s)g(s)duds - \int_t^T\int_t^s\sigma(u,s)g(s)dW_uds
\end{eqnarray*}

$\\\\$

Assuming suitable conditions to apply the stochastic Fubini theorem, we get

$\\\\$

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_t = \int_t^T\xi(s,s)g(s)ds - \int_t^T\alpha(u,T)du - \int_t^T\beta(u,T)dW_u
\end{eqnarray*}

with

\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha(u,T) = \int_u^T\mu(u,s)g(s)ds \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \beta(u,T) = \int_u^T\sigma(u,s)g(s)ds
\end{eqnarray*}

Applying Ito's lemma, we find

$\\\\$

\begin{eqnarray*}
dF_t &=& -\xi(t,t)g(t)dt + \alpha(t,T)dt + \beta(t,T)dW_t\\
&=& -\xi(t,t)g(t)dt + \int_t^T\left(\mu(t,s)dt + \sigma(t,s)dW_t\right)g(s)ds\\
&=& -\xi(t,t)g(t)dt + \int_t^Td\xi(t,s)g(s)ds
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, I have two questions :

- Is my proof correct ?
- Is there a more clever and faster answer ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble to understand your notation
$$
\int_t^Td\xi(t,s)g(s)\,ds\,.
$$
What is the meaning of this when you switch from the differential form $dF_t$ to the integral form
$$
F_t=F_0-\int_0^tg(s)\,\xi(s,s)\,ds\,+\quad?
$$
Surely, in the deterministic case when $\sigma\equiv 0\,$ we have by ordinary calculus
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=-\xi(t,t)\,g(t)+\int_t^T\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\xi(t,s)\,g(s)\,ds\,,
$$
or, in integral form
$$\tag{0}
F_t=F_0-\int_0^tg(s)\,\xi(s,s)\,ds+\int_0^t\int_u^T\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\xi(u,s)\,g(s)\,ds\,du\,.
$$
To get to the bottom of the stochastic case I consider only the case $\mu\equiv 0,\sigma\not\equiv 0,g\equiv1$ to simplify notation.

From $\xi(t,s)=\xi(0,s)+\int_0^t\sigma(u,s)\,dW_u$ we get (using stochastic Fubini)
\begin{align}
F_t&=\int_t^T\xi(t,s)\,ds=\int_t^T\xi(0,s)\,ds+\int_t^T\left(\int_0^t\sigma(u,s)\,dW_u\right)\,ds\\
&=\int_t^T\xi(0,s)\,ds+\int_0^t\int_t^T\sigma(u,s)\,ds\,dW_u\,.
\end{align}
By Ito's formula,
$$\tag{1}
dF_t=-\xi(0,t)\,dt+\left(\int_t^T\sigma(t,s)\,ds\right)dW_t-\left(\int_0^t\sigma(u,t)\,dW_u\right)\,dt\,.
$$
The last term in (1) can be combined with the first term and gives
\begin{align}\tag{2}
dF_t&=-\xi(t,t)\,dt+\left(\int_t^T\sigma(t,s)\,ds\right)dW_t\,.
\end{align}
In integral form, (2) is
$$\tag{3}\boxed{
F_t=F_0-\int_0^t\xi(s,s)\,ds+\int_0^t\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)\,ds\,dW_u\,.}
$$
By stochastic Fubini, this is
$$\tag{4}
F_t=F_0-\int_0^t\xi(s,s)\,ds+\int_0^T\int_0^{s\wedge t}\sigma(u,s)\,dW_u\,ds\,.
$$
Using
$$
d\xi(t,s)=\sigma(t,s)\,dW_t
$$
one could write (4) as
$$\tag{5}\boxed{
F_t=F_0-\int_0^t\xi(s,s)\,ds+\int_0^T\big\{\xi(s\wedge t,s)-\xi(0,s)\big\} \,ds\,.}
$$
It is fairly easy to see that (0) can also be written in the same form. In other words, (5) is the form that comprises the deterministic and the stochastic case.

Comment: If you switch $dW_t$ and $ds$ in (2), you get the anwser to the initial question, no ?

Comment: In (2) you can't switch $dW_t$ and $ds$. To do so you need to put this equation into integral form and use Fubini. That's what I have done.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but I don't understand your question "What is the meaning ...". If you switch $dWt$ and $ds$ in (2), with your dynamic for $\xi$ you get exactly $$dF_t = -\xi(t,t)dt + \int_t^T\left(\sigma(t,s)dW_t\right)ds = -\xi(t,t)dt + \int_t^Td\xi(t,s)ds$$ so the meaning is just your equation (3). For my part, I am having trouble with your first equation (1). Where does the last $dt$ factor come from ? I mean, if $G_t = \int_0^tg(u,t)dW_u$, you just write $dG_t = g(t,t)dW_t + \int_0^t(\partial_tg(u,t)dt)dW_u$. It's may be obvious, but I have never seen this kind of generalization

Comment: Sorry but why we can't switch ?

Comment: We will get to the point where I can explain to you why we can't switch. Before that, the term $\int_0^t(\partial_tg(u,t)\,dt)\,dW_u$ in your $dG_t$ looks strange to me. I prefer to 'pull' $dt$ out of this integral and write this as $(\int_0^t(\partial_tg(u,t)\,dW_u)\,dt\,.$ There you have the $dt$ factor in my eq. (3). In general I think is is a source of much confusion to do hocus pocus with those equations in differential form. We know that in Ito calculus the only rigorous meaning is always the integral form.

Comment: It remains strange for you if I pull the $dt$ term out of your integral? What is the meaning of your integral when you convert your $dG_t$ to $G$ ? Perhaps eq. (0) is what you should study.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even if you "pull" the $dt$ term out of the integral, it remains strange for me. Can you give me the proof please ? About the "switch", there is no ambiguities for me because

\begin{array}
\int_0^t \int_u^T d\xi(u,s)ds &=& \int_0^t\int_u^T \left(\sigma(u,s)dW_u\right)ds\\
&=& \int_0^t\int_u^T \sigma(u,s)dsdW_u
\end{array}

Comment: The term $\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)\,dW_u$ in your first line means what ? You integrate over $u$ from $u$ to $T$ ? Don't get it . Try the same with $du$ instead of $dW_u$ to see what kind of hocus pocus that is.

Comment: There isn't "my" $dG_t$, I'm just talking about your proof, because in my proof I don't use this kind of elements.

Comment: Sorry but you can't isolate the terms like that, I don't write just $\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)dW_u$. Obviously that does not make sense but no problem with 

$$
\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)dW_uds = \left(\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)ds\right)dW_u$$
$$

Comment: Disregarding your terms $\int_u^Td\xi(u,s)\,ds$ and $\int_u^T(\sigma(u,s)\,dW_u)\,ds$ and keeping only your last one $(\int_u^T\sigma(u,s)\,ds)\,dW_u$ you arrived at my (2) and (3). IMHO this doesn't mean that the intermediate steps make any sense to me. Let's end the discussion it is going in circles.

Comment: Ok as you want. Even if we don't agree thank you for your time.